# Using route and proxy with a NGINX virtualserver K8s config

Tags: kubernetes, ingress-nginx

I have a kinda weird set up where I have a general url([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) that terminates on an F5 that points to a nginx VS on an EKS cluster that has a localized domain([www.ue1.example.com](http://www.ue1.example.com)).

So the flow is user -->> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) --> F5 --> F5 xforwards host header of [www.ue1.example.com](http://www.ue1.example.com) --> nginx vs --> web service that is licenses for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

nginx needs a host of [www.ue1.example.com](http://www.ue1.example.com) but then convert it to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) before sending it to the web service.

So is there a way to route to a virtulserverroute AND proxy the host header as well. Here are the relevant configs. Not sure where to put the proxy information.

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  host: example.ue1.eexchange.com
  routes:
    - path: /
      route: example/example

apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServerRoute
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  upstreams:
    - name: example-service
      service: example
      port: 80
  subroutes:
    - path: /
      action:
        pass: example-service
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to apply this to the vsr.

```
  subroutes:
    - path: /
      action:
        proxy:
          upstream: example-service
          requestHeaders:
            set:
            - name: Host
              value: <target fqdn>
            - name: Origin
              value: http://<target fqdn>
```